# can we make Eclipse Plugin for JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, eclipse-plugin

I am new in Eclipse plugin development . I would like to create plugin for my web application which is using common javascript library (.js).

Is it possible to create eclipse plugin for chrom browser so that other users can use my library code but not able to see my library code .

Comment: Eclipse plugins run in Eclipse not in a browser or anywhere else. Browsers may have their own plugin system but that is a completely different thing.

Comment: Is it possible to make Eclipse Plugin which will load external library ?